# Пропадает закрывающая двойная кавыча

Tags: java

Использую liquibase для создания, обновления БД и загрузки начальных данных.
Наблюдаю следующее. Если значение поля заканчивается знаком двойной кавычки("), то она пропадает. Как вернуть ее на место?

**toys.csv**

```
id:name
1;кукла "Маша"
2;котик "Вася"
```

**кусок xml**

```
<changeSet id="20160404135456" author="sam">
    <createTable tableName="toys">
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
    <loadData encoding="UTF-8"
              file="config/liquibase/toys.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="toys">
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

В результате в БД полчаю

```
1;кукла "Маша
2;котик "Вася
```

От диалекта БД не зависит

Comment: Попробуй формат `1;"кукла """Маша"""`.

Comment: @Vadzim Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант экранирования в CSV:

```
1;"кукла """Маша"""
```